# ‘This application does not exist’ while uploading app to app engine

Tags: java, android, google-app-engine

When I upload using graddle `./gradlew backend:appengineUpdate` I get 404 Application does not exist. That's not true. App exist and the app id is fine.

What is the reason of getting this?

Comment: No matter what.. even if you write the answer from the beginning is better to form the question as a question..

Comment: there you go... not exactly a question but I got your point

Comment: But you need a question.. something with a question mark (?) :) At the moment is still just a statement.. which usually would be closed as `unclear what you are asking`

Comment: Is it really neccessary to write "What is wrong here?" in situation like this?

Comment: It's not necessary, but generally if you want good answers you have to write a good question

Comment: I would argue that it is necessary.. By definition it should be a question http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask and if it's not a question it shouldn't be here.. You could say what's wrong or even better you could write something among the lines: `Why I'm getting 'This appli...' while uploading the app for the first time?`. The whole purpose of SO

Comment: Hey, I know the rules but let's be reasonable. I've updated the question to meet the rulles strictly now, but you guys should know that I spend good ammount of time looking for this answer on the several groups couple of times. I never found one on SO. Did this in good faith to help other people, I'm sure there are some out there ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is something that might help if you tried all the other ways found on the internet, but you can aswell try it as the first one.

If you are sure the app id is correct and your app exist this error will sound stupid. In fact this is something related to the ouauth.

Open console and look under your home directory for files starting with `.appcfg_oauth2`. Delete them.

Now try to reupload your app again. If you use gradle and making a java backend it will look something like

```
./gradlew mybackendapp:appengineUpdate
```

At some point you’ll be redirected to the browser, when you should login to proper Google account. When you do that you’ll get some weird string, which they wan’t you to copy into app. But where….? Don’t worry, just get back to the console and paste this into it. The process of uploading should continue and finish… successfully this time.